# JQuery bootstrap modal dialog is not displayed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to display sign up form in modal window using Bootstrap template.

My sample should be opened by pressing [R] element but  it's not. However in the example (http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modals-tutorial.php) it does.

The attribute seems not to be working correctly in my example:

```
data-toggle="modal"
```

Why?

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mfc7M/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Twitter Bootstrap Modals Example</title>
<body>
    <div id="reg-model-dialog" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
        <div class="modal-header">  <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a> 
                <h3>Registration</h3> 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="search-tbl">
                <tr>
                    <td>Email:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="reg-email" id="reg-email" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="reg-pwd" id="reg-pwd" value="" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Call to action</a>  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a> 
        </div>
    </div>  <a data-toggle="modal" href="#regstration" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="reg-dialog-btn">R</a>
```

AND

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$("#reg-model-dialog").modal();
    /*   $('#reg-dialog-btn').click(function(){
                                                $('#reg-model-dialog').css('display','inline');
                                             }); */

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a JS solution:

```
$('#reg-dialog-btn').click(function () {
    $('#reg-model-dialog').modal('show');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mfc7M/5/)

In this case, the `#reg-dialog-btn`'s `data-*` attributes are unnecessary.

The Bootstrap Modal's `show`, `hide` and `toggle` methods are documented [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).

I personally dislike putting too many `data-*` attributes in the HTML as it mixes structure with behavior, but setting a `data-target` or `href` attribute to `"#reg-model-dialog"` as in @Pigueiras' solution will work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

The `href` attribute is wrong, you have to make reference to the modal ID. In your case, the R button should be:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#reg-model-dialog" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" 
         id="reg-dialog-btn">R</a>
```

Instead of:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#regstration" ...></a>
```

You can look at it working here: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eugip9/xcBr8/)